# cache coherence for SMP is assured by HW or SW?

Tags: linux, caching

Does software need to do something to ensure the coherence for SMP environment,
if it is not solved by the HW, can some one tell me what method or API we can use in the linux kernel programming?
THX!!!

Answer (score 0):

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/papers/isca91_coherence.pdf has a comparison of HW v SW approaches for cache coherency.

[DMA cache coherence management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132284/dma-cache-coherence-management) discusses consideration re: whether to disable cache coherency hardware mechanisms (such as snooping) for improved performance with a device driver which does DMA.